# How to remove the hyperlink at chapter number (or add the hyperlink at section number) when using tocloft and hyperref

Tags: xetex, hyperref, tocloft

When I am using the packages of tocloft and hyperref, in the Table of Contents, the hyperlink will appear at the chapter number but not available at the numbers of section and subsection.
As shown in the following figure.
[image]
Is there any method to unify the hyperlinks at chapter and (sub)section numbers?

Comment: Please provide a complete example to show how the `tocloft` and `hyperref` are loaded and used/configured.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You must be employing some non-default settings for `tocloft`. Please do tell us exactly what you're doing -- and also which document class you employ. Please also confirm whether or not you use XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks very much, I could not provide a demo code because it is a thesis document with a complex .cls file.
But I have solved the problem. It is caused by the indent settings for the (sub)sections in the template. If I annote these two statements, the problem is naturally solved, the indent settings go like this:

\titlecontents{section}[4em]{}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{\hspace*{-2em}}{~\titlerule*[0.6pc]{$.$}~\contentspage} % section Indent
\titlecontents{subsection}[6.5em]{}{\contentslabel{2.5em}}{\hspace*{-2em}}{~\titlerule*[0.6pc]{$.$}~\contentspage} % subsection Indent